# Navigation between two Angular children routes

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

I have the following routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    outlet: 'primary',
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'briefs',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'menu',
            component: BrieflistMenuComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'main',
            component: BrieflistComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'brief/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'menu',
            component: BriefMenuComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'main',
            component: BriefComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/briefs',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

- How can I navigate between `briefs/` and `brief/XXX/` using `this.router.navigate(...)`? I tried `this.router.navigate(['brief', id]);` but I get the following error: `Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet`.
- How to redirect all undefined paths to `briefs/`?

I use Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out by myself.
For the first question, one of the two outlets should not be named.
For the second question, I added `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/briefs', pathMatch: 'full' }` to the children of the main `''` path.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    outlet: 'primary',
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'briefs',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'menu',
            component: BrieflistMenuComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            // outlet: 'main',
            component: BrieflistComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'brief/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'menu',
            component: BriefMenuComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            // outlet: 'main',
            component: BriefComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/briefs',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```